# recheck outer if boolean true or false within it's else

Tags: if-statement, kendo-ui, return, boolean

My goal is to recheck variable `coolFeature` boolean value from it's `else`

```
    if (coolFeature) { // want to run this again after value becomes true in else below
        $("#Editor").data("kendoWindow").width = '600';
        $("#Editor").data("kendoWindow").title("Format Feature - " + Type + ' #' + graphic.attributes.OBJECTID);
        $('#ndt').hide();
    } else {
        $("#Editor").data("kendoWindow").title("Edit Attributes - " + Type + ' #' + graphic.attributes.OBJECTID);
        $('#ndt').show();
        $("#ndt").click(function() {
            $(this).data('clicked', true);
            $("#Editor").data("kendoWindow").hide();
            coolFeature = "true"; // want to reset to True here, then run the actions under initial if
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need simple recursion, I can't see the entire code so I can't tell exactly.

```
var myFunction = function(coolFeature) {
    if(coolFeature) {
        console.log("Cool");
    } else {
        myFunction(true);
    }
};

myFunction(false);
```